# multiple sources of damage reduction

Tags: dnd-5e, damage-resistance

In our current part we have a tiefling druid, a sorcerer, and an Oath of the Ancients paladin giving Aura of Protection and Aura of Warding

1. The tiefling has Hellish Resistance so has resistance to fire damage and gets a buff to dex saves from Aura of Protection from the paladin
2. The sorcerer launches off a fireball that results in friendly fire
3. The tiefling makes the dex save (with the assistance from Aura of Protection)

As per the spell they take half damage. The hellish resistance gives them a base resistance to the fire damage even without Aura of Warding.

Would the damage be halved from the dex save and then halved again from resistance so would they essentially only take 1/4 of the resulting damage roll?

Comment: I’ve closed this as a duplicate since it has been asked before.